# Are there alternative words for 'subcomponent'?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I have a situation as follows:

> In a score, there are 2 main components - Section A and Section B.
>
> In each components, there are **subcomponent**. (Example: Section A have 2 subcomponents - Section 1 and Section 2.)

Are there any word(s) alternatives for the word 'subcomponent'?

Comment: Subcomponent is good in itself, I'd say.

Comment: Components are divided into subcomponents.  Sections are divided into subsections. Then you could introduce components making up subsections.

Comment: Take a synonym of the noun [component](http://thesaurus.com/browse/component?s=ts) and prefix it with *sub-*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say the two *sections* are each divided into two ***parts***, or two ***elements***.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to J.R.'s answer, you can even say items, or subitems